# Track a click() event on Google Plus Button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to capture the Google+ Button Click, but unsuccessful in doing so.

I have used "onstartinteraction" in my implementation and unfortunately this method gets triggered even when the user hovers the mouse over the G+ Button.

I tried using "data-callback", but, this method gets triggered only after the user clicks the G+ Button & log's in on the popped up Google+ Login Window. **My requirement is to just capture the click when a user clicks the G+ Button**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the .cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Plus Click</title>
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")
@Scripts.Render("https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js")
<meta name="view" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="none" data-onstartinteraction="plusClick">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function plusClick(data) {
alert('G PlusOne Button Clicked');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="none" data-onstartinteraction="plusClick" onClick="plusClick.call(this,event)">
```

With onClick yuo can fire your Function.
NB. `plusClick.call(this,event)` inside the function **plusClick** `this` scope are the button you have clicked and your `data` is the event.

Comment: Sorry. the onClick did not help. It's just not getting fired. Probably the class "g-plusone" does not allow us to use onClick.

Comment: uhm...see the commenti with link of Boaz.